# Restricting access to Solr EC2 Server with a Github Pages front-end

Tags: solr, amazon-ec2, github-pages, cidr

I've been trying to restrict access to my Solr server running on an EC2 instance, but I haven't been able to get the EC2 security group restrictions worked out.

I've tried adding 192.30.252.153/32 and 192.30.252.154/32 (the Github Pages IP addresses?), but my front-end on Github Pages won't load. However, when I allow access for my current IP in the EC2 Security Group tab, the search works fine.

I have a feeling it might have to do with my CIDR notation, or perhaps I'm allowing access from the wrong IP addresses? Thanks!

Comment: Why would your server be accessed by the github servers?  Wouldn't it be the web browsers that are rendering your page that would be accessing your server?  If not, please explain the setup in more detail.

Comment: Essentially, I'm making AJAX requests from the server to display search results to the browser. I'm using Github Pages for the front-end and EC2 for the backend.

Comment: Wouldn't AJAX requests be made by the browser, not the server?